# Why isn't there a NilReferenceError in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

Why is `NoMethodError` not differentiated for `nil` in Ruby?

Calling a method on nil is an extremely common error and is usually caused by incorrect data being provided to the program. A `NoMethodError` on any other class usually implies an error in the code itself (e.g. why were you calling `reconnect` on a `Document`? There is likely an error in the code).

What problems are created if I add the following code to my project?

```
NilReferenceError = Class.new(NoMethodError)
class NilClass
  def method_missing(symbol, *args)
    raise NilReferenceError, "undefined method `#{symbol}' for nil:NilClass", caller
  end
end
```

I want to do this because when I am triaging exceptions, a `NilReferenceError` is likely to be caused by bad data and the root cause is likely in another location (validation of input, for example). By contrast, a `NoMethodError` is likely to be a programming error rooted exactly at the line of the exception (easier to fix and also highly likely to happen 100% of the time).

What are the negative effects of adding code like that to my project?

Comment: Here's a brief discussion of this topic: https://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-01/much-ado-about-nothing

Comment: Why would they be differentiated? Both are programmer errors - one for calling a wrong method, one for not validating data - and you don't want to catch them in most cases, so they both typically crash out. It is trivial for a programmer to separate `NoMethodError: undefined method 'push' for nil:NilClass` and `NoMethodError: undefined method 'mush' for []:Array`. On the other hand, changing base classes (especially one as key as `NilClass`) might break things if a library depends on the standard behaviour.

Comment: What is the point of having a special error class for no method error just when the receiver is `nil`? You can tell that the receiver is `nil` from the error message of an ordinary no method error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with monkeypatching `nil` to show a more descriptive error message, but it's not going to solve the root cause of the problem, which is coding practice that permits and propagates nil values.

Consider the following very contrived example:

```
def do_something(input)
  object = fetch_something_with(input[element])
  do_something_with(object)
end
```

A couple of ways this might blow up:

- `input` hash does not contain `element`, and passes `nil` into `fetch_something_with`
- `fetch_something_with` returns nil (by design or upon failure), which gets passed into `do_something_with`

An alternative approach might be:

```
def do_something(input)
  object = fetch_something_with(validated_input)

  object && return do_something_with(object)
end

def validated_input(input)
  input.fetch(element) # fetch raises an exception if the value is not present
end
```

A bit more code, but it gives us peace of mind that this code isn't going to silently pass `nil` down the line to fail at some later point.

Of course, it doesn't make sense to be this paranoid in every single method, but it is good practice to have well thought out boundaries in your code, either at method or object level. Having `nil` slip by frequently is a sign that these borders need some strengthening.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just habits from other programming languages. In ruby, nil is a first class object, like an integer, a hash or your own class object.

After you see the `"NoMethodError: undefined method xxx for nil:NilClass"` error once or twice, you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that, when doing something like `b=nil; b.say_hello;`, ruby will give you "undefined method `say_hello' for nil:NilClass (**NoMethodError**)" instead of something like (as in your claim) "undefined method `say_hello' for nil:NilClass (**NilReferenceError**)"?

Ruby is not wrong for this since `nil` is an object like other objects. It has methods like `to_s`, so ruby can't ban any call by just raising an exception saying "because it is nil, you cannot do anything. I will give you a NilReferenceError".

You can surely do as your code above if you know that what you are doing may prevent ruby's default behavior.